# Cannot Save Data Frame to Elasticsearch during spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

During Spark Stream processing and Saving Data Frame to Elastic Search facing below error:

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot determine write shards for [custAct_index/custAct_index_type]; 
    likely its format is incorrect (maybe it contains illegal characters?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use lower case letters for elasticsearch index.
Use [custact_index/custact_index_type] instead of [custAct_index/custAct_index_type].